# KDE: how do I make applications present on all activities by default

Tags: kde, window-manager, kde-activities

When I'm at work, I use KDE activities and map them to my projects. I always use the same applications on every project, so I'd like to keep my windows visible when I change the activity. For the moment, what I do is go through every window, right click on the title bar, and check the checkbox that makes the window appear on all activities. How can I configure my windows default value for this choice? I'd like every window to appear on all activities by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question may be old, but I think I have found the perfect solution.

- Go to **System Settings** > **Window Behaviour** > **Window Rules**
- Add a new Rule
- Mark all window properties as '**Unimportant**'
- Select all '**Window**' types like in the screenshot
  [image: Select all 'Window' types]
- In the tab '**Size & Position**', tick '**Activities**' and configure it as '**Apply initially**' and '**All Activites**', like in the screenshot
  [image: In the tab 'Size & Position', tick 'Activities' and configure it as 'Apply initially' and 'All Activites']
- Click '**Ok**'

This should set all windows to be on all activities by default.

Comment: Looks awesome! I can't wait to test that at work tomorrow! And yes, the question is old, but the problem is still very present.

Comment: Woops, forgot to test until now, but it works like a charm! Many, many thanks!

Comment: In the mean time, the answer is old as well, but this still works :-)  The settings are under System Settings > Window Management > Window Rules now.  The (new?) Detect Window Properties button makes things easy, as you can click an existing window and use its settings to create rules.

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but might help. Idea that comes to my mind is to search for such windows with `xwininfo` or `xdotool search --name WINDOWNAME` and then try to "inject" mouse clicks or - this is easier - keystrokes ( example: `xdotool search --name WINNAME key ctrl+c`. that results in such setting (  "alt+space" usually gets WM window options, later arrows... this should be possible to do by keystrokes injection ).

Comment: Not very elegant indeed, but if there is no other solution, I guess I should look into that...

Comment: That's why I've wrote it. If nothing better will be around, try this shot.

Comment: I've tried to find out on http://community.kde.org/Main_Page and http://techbase.kde.org/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=activity and http://api.kde.org , but with no success.

Comment: It seems there is no solution just the workaround you and I proposed... [for the moment](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=285055)

Comment: Or solution needs going down to C++ implementation. I tried checking out API, but I haven't seen anything suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the question here : http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=98797&p=211999#p211999 and it appears not closing the windows when shutting the computer down makes them reappear on startup with the same options, which is a good workaround for this problem.