# Force certain programs to work on all Desktops AND Activities

Tags: kubuntu, plasma5, kde-activities

**Config**: I'm running Kubuntu 21.04 with KDE Plasma 5.21.4 on a Dell Precision 5750.  I use a combination of Desktops and Activities to compartmentalize my work. Loving it.

**Problem** One minor question.  When I reboot, I have to go into a few applications and set them (using Alt-F3) to "All Desktops" and "All Activities".  Mostly communication like things, such as Slack, Zoom, Telegram, etc..  This is especially a problem with Zoom. Any NEW zoom window requires me to go find it, on whatever desktop/activity it is on.

**Question** Is there any way to force these to always be "All Desktops" and "All Activities"?

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30088/102177

Answer (score 0):

Create a new window management rule in the plasma settings/windows managemente/window rules. The default filter is to specify a windows class, make sure to set something there or set it to call classes and filter the window title.

You can also use the detect window properties button and click on the zoom window and select a few attributes that indetify the window (its a bit confusing, select the window, click for example window title and then close the popup).

Once that is set, in the rule window under size and position, add a property, select Activity and then force or temporarly force to the one you need.